# Why does the location mistake in UTM projection in GRASS GIS does not make any difference?

Tags: gis, qgis, utm

I had to create a buffer of a line in UTM 44N but I mistakely entered the location as UTM 45N in GRASS GIS. Later I made buffers in both projections and importing it later in QGIS I found that they both align perfectly and clipping a raster also produces the same statistics. Can someone please help me understand why this is?

Comment: I would assume that QGIS just does "on-the-fly" re-projection for you. So layers that are correctly defined in different CRS will indeed overlay correctly.

Comment: Hi @Micha how would you suggest to clip the raster than? Should QGIS projection, raster projection and vector be all in the same CRS and if so whose CRS should the rest be converted to?

Comment: Whenever I perform any spatial operations, such as buffering or clipping, I reproject all layers in advance to the same projection. You should load each layer and then "Save as..." and choose one suitable projection for all of them.

Comment: Thank you @Micha but is it absolutely necessary to change the CRS as well? Can I not keep it to WGS 84 so that all the layers are visible given that I have converted both the vector and raster in the same UTM.